# Python - Plotting a raster image/contour plot with XY and Z points

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, raster

I have a set of X and Y coordinates and each point has a different pixel value - the Z quantity. I would like to plot these values using a raster or contour plot.

I am having difficulty doing this because there is no mathematical relationship between the pixel value and the X and Y coordinates.

I have created an array for the range of x and y values and I have tried constructing a dictionary where I can look up the value of z using a concatenated x and y string. At the moment I am having an index issue and I am wondering if there is a better way of achieving this?

My code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

XY_Zpoints = {'11':8,
             '12':8,
             '13':8,
             '14':6,
             '21':6,
             '22':8,      
             '23':6,
             '24':6,
             '31':8,
             '32':3, 
             '33':8,
             '34':6,
             '41':8,
             '42':3, 
             '43':3,
             '44':8,
                   }

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(1,4,4), np.linspace(1,4,4))

z = XY_Zpoints[str(x)+str(y)]

# Plot the grid
plt.imshow(z)
plt.spectral()
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a dictionary, you can use a numpy array where the position of each pixel value coresponds to the x and y coordinates. For your example this array would look like:

```
z = np.array([[8, 8, 8, 6], [6, 8, 6, 6], [8, 3, 8, 6], [8, 3, 3, 8]])
```

To access the pixel value at x = 2 and y = 3, for example you can do this:

```
x = 2
y = 3
pixel = z[x-1][y - 1]
```

z can be displayed with:

```
imshow(z)
```

Comment: Sorry I have just been thinking about this. It seems that using your approach you define the array using the pixel value. This is a good approach if you have a precise grid of values. Is it also possible to define an array and then assign the pixel value to a location/point on that array?

Comment: A precise grid of values as opposed to what? Do you want to handle missing values?

Comment: Sorry ignore me I was just thinking if you had a point occurring midway between points in your specified array say at 2.5 that might pose a problem but thinking about it, it would be quite easy to round up or increase the resolution of the grid. Thanks again for your help.